# подключение нужной версии jquery

Tags: jquery

Делаю апгрейд на сайте. Изначально сайт юзает версию jquery 3.2.1. Её я и стал использовать при апгрейде. Но нашёл некий плагин, который для своей личной работы использует 1.10.2. Этот плагин является одним из элементов апгрейда и я его прикрутил на сайт. Подключение двух версий сразу на одной странице - это, наверное, плохой вариант, поэтому я хочу научить плагин использовать мою версию 3.2.1.

Когда включаю его на ней, то в консоли получаю варнинг

```
Uncaught TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function
    at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.load (jquery.js?v=1582769839:9823)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (megamenu.js?v=1582769839:64)
    at mightThrow (jquery.js?v=1582769839:3583)
    at process (jquery.js?v=1582769839:3651)
```

как я понимаю из текста, функция `indexOf` была переписана в версии 3.2.1 и не подходит теперь для плагина. Прошу знающих людей:

1. построчно "прочитать" код ошибки и объяснить, что каждая из строчек
   ошибки означает. Именно построчно, а не вцелом.
2. Как правильно выходить из такой ситуации? Как я понимаю надо в файле скрипта плагина megamenu.js добавить эту функцию, выдрав её из старой версии 1.10.2 так, чтоб он не лез за ней в новую версию 3.2.1?

[1.10.2.js](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js)

```
jQuery.fn.load = function( url, params, callback ) {
    if ( typeof url !== "string" && _load ) {
        return _load.apply( this, arguments );
    }

    var selector, response, type,
        self = this,
        off = url.indexOf(" ");
```

[3.2.1.js](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js)

```
jQuery.fn.load = function( url, params, callback ) {
    var selector, type, response,
        self = this,
        off = url.indexOf( " " );
```

Вызов функции load() нашёл в двух файлах. В первом она выглядит так:

```
 $(window).load(function(){
    if ($('.ets_mn_submenu_full_height').length > 0 ){
    var ver_sub_height = $('.ets_mn_submenu_full_height').height();
    $('.ets_mn_submenu_full_height').find('.mm_columns_ul').css("min-height",ver_sub_height);
 }
 });
```

во втором так

```
function(p) {
    if ($isMobile = !1, /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) && ($isMobile = !0), /Bot/i.test(navigator.userAgent) && (window.isSearchBot = !0), window.isMobile = $isMobile, 1 == $isMobile) {
        function e() {
            for (var e = document.body.querySelectorAll(".t-cover__carrier"), t = p(window).height(), o = 0, i = 0, r = e.length; i < r; i++) - 1 < (a = (n = e[i]).style).height.indexOf("vh") && (o = parseInt(a.height) / 100, c = Math.round(t * o) + "px", (s = (s = p(n).parent(".t-cover")) && s[0]) && (d = s.querySelector(".t-cover__filter"), l = s.querySelector(".t-cover__wrapper"), d && (d.style.height = c), l && (l.style.height = c), a.height = s.style.height = c));
            var n, a, c, s, d, l, u = document.body.querySelectorAll("[data-height-correct-vh]");
            for (t = p(window).height(), o = 0, i = 0, r = u.length; i < r; i++) - 1 < (a = (n = u[i]).style).height.indexOf("vh") && (o = parseInt(a.height) / 100, c = t + "px", s = p(n).parent(".t-cover"), a.height = c)
        }
        p(document).ready(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                e()
            }, 400)
        }), p(window).load(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                e()
            }, 400)
        })
    }
```

Логически не понимаю причём тут url.

Comment: "минусующих" попросил бы объяснить, что именно в вопросе вызывает негодование

Comment: построчно у вас там стек вызова написан, ничего полезного в данном случае он не несет. а indexOf не функция, потому что url имеет значение undefined скорее всего. Прежде чем заниматься разработкой плагинов, почитайте хоть немнго про отладку. поставьте в своей плагине точку останова на данную строку, и проверьте значения.

Answer (score 0):

В плагине найдите код url.indexOF и посмотрите что он пытается выполнить, попробуйте перед ним прописать console.log(url) чтобы в консоли при выполнении увидеть содержимое url и понять - применим ли к нему вообще indexOf.

Глобально - indexOf - метод js и не зависит от версии jQuery. Скорее всего после замены jQuery у вас посыпались функции наполнения переменной url.

Но это тоже странно, т.к. при развитии jquery его функциональность и синтаксис только расширяли, не меняя старое, чтобы всем не приходилось переписывать свои сайты после обновления. Единственное - начиная с версии 2.х.х убрали поддержку IE с 6 по 8 версию, поддерживает ток 9+

Comment: Я сделал то, что вы сказали и сравнил эти участки кода в разных версиях  jquery и добавил сравнение в вопрос. В новой версии убрали проверку, видимо из-за её отсутствия происходит эта ошибка. Однако я вас не совсем понимаю. Почему indexOf надо искать в плагине? Это ж в библиотеке jquery происходит вызов этого метода. Как я понимаю мне надо найти откуда в данную функцию function( url, params, callback ) приходит переменная url и в том месте, откуда она приходит и прописать отсутствующею проверку. Если я не прав, поправьте, а если прав, то подскажите как найти это место, откуда приходит url ?

Comment: Вот мы уже ближе к сути)
А где у вас в коде плагина используется .load() ?
По идее там должен быть url первым аргументом

Comment: ну вот ещё ближе к сути. нашёл те места, где идёт обращение к функции load() и их тоже вставил в вопрос. Вопрос у меня постепенно трансформируется и теперь он такой: как прописать в эти места отсутствующую проверку?

Comment: Тут load - событие готовности страницы, включая картинки. Попробуйте заменить на $(document).ready(function() { в первом случае, а во втором убить вовсе, т.к. там последовательно вызывается одна и та-же функция на  загрузку DOM без картинок и с картинками.
Если это вызовет проблемы, то можно попробовать использовать стандартный в js window.onload